# Issue populating an array of objects dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am facing an issue when populating an array of the object dynamically in javascript. I have this sample data as below:

[image]

I have to populate following arrays with the data from above:

```js
c1_Arr = [];
c2_Arr = [];

var torontoObj = { arName: 'تورونتو', enName: 'Totonto', value: 0 };
var parisObj = { arName: 'باريس', enName: 'Paris', value: 0 };
var londonObj = { arName: 'لندن', enName: 'London', value: 0 };
```

Now I am looping through the data to set the values from data as:

```js
var resultCount = results.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    var data = results.features[i].attributes;

    parisObj.value = data.Paris;
    londonObj.value = data.London;
    torontoObj.value = data.Toronto;

    if (data.Ind_ID === 101) {
        c1_Arr.push(parisObj);
        c1_Arr.push(londonObj);
        c1_Arr.push(torontoObj);
    }
}
console.log(c1_Arr);
```

I am getting this data in console:

[image]

Here I am getting the values of the object i.e. **Ind_ID = 102** instead of the object values of **Ind_ID = 101** (first object).

> How to get the values of the required object using the Ind_ID?

Comment: Please help potential answeres by posting an example of what you expect the result of your function to look like. Also post the actual values of the input data, not just a screenshot, so it can be copied into a code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because even though you have the if condition there but you are updating the value of the objects in the loop and since you have already pushed them objects you still have the reference in the main objects. They get overwritten.

Create the 3 objects (torontoObj, etc.) inside the loop.

Comment: Something like this
`var resultCount = results.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    var data = results.features[i].attributes;

    if (data.Ind_ID === 101) {
        parisObj.value = data.Paris;
        londonObj.value = data.London;
        torontoObj.value = data.Toronto;
        c1_Arr.push(parisObj);
        c1_Arr.push(londonObj);
        c1_Arr.push(torontoObj);
    }
}
console.log(c1_Arr);`

Answer (score 1):

Reference is getting updated in the second iteration (where **Ind_ID** is 102)

You should rather do

```
var resultCount = results.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    var data = results.features[i].attributes;

    if (data.Ind_ID === 101) {
        parisObj.value = data.Paris;
        londonObj.value = data.London;
        torontoObj.value = data.Toronto;
        c1_Arr.push(parisObj);
        c1_Arr.push(londonObj);
        c1_Arr.push(torontoObj);
    }
}
console.log(c1_Arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object values are getting updated even after being set inside the `if` loop, simply because, you're not limiting it from being updated.

You could probably do one of the following 2 things:

1. **The simpler one:**

Extract the values of `Paris`, `London` and `Toronto` fields of `data` only if the `Ind
_ID` is `101`.

like this:

```
var resultCount = results.features.length;
for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
    var data = results.features[i].attributes;

    if (data.Ind_ID === 101) {
        parisObj.value = data.Paris;
        londonObj.value = data.London;
        torontoObj.value = data.Toronto;
        c1_Arr.push(parisObj);
        c1_Arr.push(londonObj);
        c1_Arr.push(torontoObj);
    }
}
console.log(c1_Arr);
```

2. **The more elegant one:**

Extract the array element which only matches your condition, in other words [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
    var resultCount = results.features.length;
    var data = results.features.filter(feature => feature.attributes.Ind_ID === 101);
    parisObj.value = data[0].Paris;
    londonObj.value = data[0].London;
    torontoObj.value = data[0].Toronto;
    console.log(c1_Arr);
```

Comment: The second one is wrong as its iterating the same thing again and again. You can ditch the for loop and do the inner code directly. But then there is a chance if the id doesn't exist.

Comment: oh yeah.. thanks for pointing it out.. Overlooked it while copying the code.. Thanks a lot